# Add additional labels from a DataFrame to a facet_grid with existing label

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, data-visualization, facet

I have a set data that I need to add to levels of labels. One on a single chart within the facet grid, and one from a small dataframe with entries for for each chart.

In the example below you'll see that I can add to a single chart no problem but when I try to add from the df I get the error -
`Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'wt' not found`

Preparation:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_line()
p <- p + facet_grid(. ~ cyl)

ann_text <- data.frame(mpg = 30,wt = 5,lab = "Text",
                       cyl = factor(8,levels = c("4","6","8")))

dfl <- data.frame(name = c('Jim',"Bob", "Sue"), r = c(-0.2, 0.5, -0.4))
```

Single Label:

```
p + geom_text(data = ann_text,label = "Text")
```

Multiple Labels:

```
p + geom_text(data = ann_text,label = "Text") + 
  geom_text(data = dfl, mpg = 30,wt = 5, aes(label = r))
```

The method I'm using is trying to recreate other examples I've found here on SO and elsewhere but I seem to be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working in your second code because in the second `geom_text`, your `mpg` and `wt` in not in `aes()`. Also, these two variables are absent in your `dfl`.

If you wish to have better control of the labelling of your `r` variable, you can create extra columns in `dfl` specifying the `x` and `y` location of the label, and use these variables in `geom_text(aes())`.

Note that I have modified the `y` position in the second `geom_text` to avoid overlapping "0,2" with "Text".

```r
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_line()
p <- p + facet_grid(. ~ cyl)

ann_text <- data.frame(mpg = 30,wt = 5,lab = "Text",
                       cyl = factor(8,levels = c("4","6","8")))

dfl <- data.frame(name = c('Jim',"Bob", "Sue"), r = c(-0.2, 0.5, -0.4))

p + geom_text(data = ann_text,label = "Text") + 
  geom_text(data = dfl, aes(30, 4, label = r), check_overlap = T)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is great, thanks @benson23! One thing I'm noticing though is that it is adding the first value to each chart. Is there something that needs to be tweaked so it uses the entry fro each row?

Comment: @JohnConor So you want both "Text" and "r" to each facet?

Comment: No, all 3 facets are showing 0.2 as opposed to ```-0.2, 0.5, -0.4``` per the df. Though when I use on my actual dataset it works so might not be a big problem. One other thing I am running into is that in my actual data the y axis limits vary substantially, from 0-5 to 0-60... do you know of a method to adjust the y based on the data for each individual facet?

Comment: @JohnConor The first problem is because we are mapping `labels` to the same `x` and `y` position, therefore I used the parameter `check_overlap = T` to remove overlapping texts, which in this case would be "0.5" and "-0.4". To your second question, you can use `facet_grid(. ~ cyl, scales = "free_y")`

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I'm using ```scales = "free_y"``` so when I add the label the position is not consistent. Do you know if a method to address that?

Comment: @JohnConor We should only include one question per SO post. Also, I think your new question deserves it's own post because I believe it cannot be done easily

Comment: That's fair, thanks for you help!